# Why is FreeRTOS not preempting tasks?

Tags: c, freertos, multitasking, preemption

I'm using [FreeRTOS](https://www.freertos.org) on a [Raspberry Pi Pico (R2040)](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/rp2040.html). I'm starting with a 'hello world' type program to check that I can run two tasks:

```
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "timers.h"
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void Task1(void* nothing)
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Task1\n");
        sleep_ms(1000);                             // Doesn't allow preemption
        //vTaskDelay(1 * configTICK_RATE_HZ );      // Does allow preemption
    }
}

void Task2(void* nothing)
{
    sleep_ms(500);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Task2\n");
        sleep_ms(1000);                             // Doesn't allow preemption
        //vTaskDelay(1 * configTICK_RATE_HZ );      // Does allow preemption
    }
}


void main()
{
    stdio_init_all();
    sleep_ms(2000);
    printf("\n\n\n\nHello\n\n");

    TaskHandle_t xTask1Handle = NULL;
    TaskHandle_t xTask2Handle = NULL;

    BaseType_t ret1 = xTaskCreate(Task1, "Task1", 256, 0, 10, &xTask1Handle);
    BaseType_t ret2 = xTaskCreate(Task2, "Task2", 256, 0, 10, &xTask2Handle);

    if (ret1 == pdPASS) printf("Task 1 created OK\n");
    else                printf("Task 1 failed\n");

    if (ret2 == pdPASS) printf("Task 2 created OK\n");
    else                printf("Task 2 failed\n");

    vTaskStartScheduler();

    while(1)
    {
    }
}
```

The output of the program shows that if I use `sleep_ms()` then only one task prints its output. But if I use `vTaskDelay()` then both tasks run. Presumably this means that FreeRTOS is not preempting my tasks?

In my `FreeRTOSConfig.h` file, I have enabled preemption.

```
#define configUSE_PREEMPTION                    1
#define configUSE_TIME_SLICING                  1
```

Is there something else I need to do to enable preemption?

Comment: Are you using 11.0.0?

Comment: Are you enabling the correct task modes and hardware? From the various `main.c` examples in the `Demo` subdirectory of the source, the `main` functions call `prvSetupHardware` to do system dependent hardware initialization. In one instance, this programs the timer hardware to allow interrupts for rescheduling. Also, some `vStart*Tasks` calls. All these are done _before_ calling `xTaskCreate` or `vStartScheduler`. You may want to find a demo example that is similar to your H/W (e.g. an RPi example).

Comment: How is sleep_ms implemented ? Does it disable interrupts while busy waiting ? However, why not just using vTaskDelay and friends ?

Comment: @HS2 Calling `vTaskDelay` is _cooperative_. It's a valid way to do things, but it's _not_ preemptive. OP wants something that allows the basic `while (1) { printf("Task1\n"); ms_sleep(1000); }` We can [crudely] replace `ms_sleep` with a `for` loop. OP still wants forward progress. Even simpler: we just increment a global: `while (1) { global_1++; }` and `while (1) { global_2++; }` Both should make forward progress. OP just wants the task functions to do what they would do under posix threads (e.g. under linux). A timer interrupt causes a reschedule.

Comment: @CraigEstey Maybe I didn’t get the OP intention right. But after an expired xTaskDelay a task is scheduled according to it’s priority.